# How can I copy a Matlab array to a field of an array of structs

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I have defined an array of structs as follows:

```
t3(1:num_elems) = struct('prime_idx',0,'second_idx',0,);
```

I would like to copy an array `nic` to the prime_idx field of t3, so that `t3(x).prime_idx == nic(x)` for all x. I've tried:

```
 t3.prime_idx = nic;
```

and
     [t3.prime_idx] = nic;
and 
     t3.prime_idx = [nic];
and
     [t3.prime_idx] = [nic];

and various permutations of adding `(:)` after the two array variables `t3` and `nic`.

How can I copy each element of `nic` to the corresponding `prime_idx` field of the corresponding element of t3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression s.f, where s is a struct *array*, results in a comma separated list. Thus, writing `s.f = x;` is invalid, and `[s.f] = x;` would work, but requires x to return as many outputs as s has items. What you need is to provide those outputs, e.g. like this:

```
cNic = num2cell(nic);
[t3.prime_idx] = cNic{:};
```